# How to perform a connection to a mdf database with mysql in vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I wanted to make a connection to my Clients.mdf database with MySql but I'm not finding out where the error is.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms   


Public Class Form8
     Private Kon As New
```

I wanted to make a connection to my Clients.mdf database with MySql but I'm not finding out where the error is

```
MySqlConnection("Server=C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\
ClinicaProject\Clinica.mdf ;user id= ;database= Clinica.mdf")
Private Sub Form8_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub VoltarToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VoltarToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Form1.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Select * From Consultas Where Data = '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"
    Try
        Me.DataSet1.Clear()
        Kon.Open()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, Kon)
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd
        adp.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Consultas)
        cmd.Dispose()
        adp.Dispose()
        Kon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Kon.Close()
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You didn't state the error but I'll start with [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: Server= is expecting a server for MySql not a path to file.

Comment: I think you can use Sql Server to produce a raw database dump. Then us Workbench to import the dump to MySql. But don't ask me how. :-)